# How can I load a literal value into mask (k) register?

Tags: assembly, x86, avx512

I want to load an AVX512 "k" register with a specific bit pattern.

The best I could come up with is to zero a 32-bit register, add the constant, and then move that.  There must be a shorter sequence of instructions to do this, but I can't find it.

```
   4:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax                   
   6:   05 aa aa 00 00          add    $0xaaaa,%eax                
   b:   c5 f8 92 f8             kmovw  %eax,%k7
```

Comment: Well, `mov $0xaaaa, %eax; kmovw %eax, %k7` is obviously shorter :) In terms of machine code `mov $0xaaaa, %ax` is even shorter but might not be too good due to partial register update.

Comment: That might be the best answer.  I know very little assembly...  If you put in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Doesn't kmov also support reading from memory?  It's "shorter" in that it's only 1 instruction, but that might not make it faster, or fewer bytes of instructions.

Comment: @AndyJost If possible, it might be easier to achieve the same goal using intrinsics with C or C++, especially if you are not familiar with assembly.  The compiler is very good at finding optimal instruction sequences.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Yes, but then I would need to place the literal value into memory.

Comment: @fuz I am doing runtime (JIT) assembly, so those are not an option.  FWIW, I'm using the excellent library xbyak to build functions dynamically.

Comment: @AndyJost I see.  That makes sense.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: `kmov` from memory is unfortunately mo more efficient on current CPUs than a `mov` load into a GP-integer register + `kmov %eax, %k1`, so it still costs a port-5 uop, even on IceLake.  (https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/)  https://www.uops.info/html-instr/KMOVW_K_M16.html.  mov-immediate into a GP-integer register normally makes more sense.

Comment: @Andy: you can always look at what compilers emit for intrinsics, e.g. for `_mm512_maskz_add_ps (__mmask16 k, __m512 a, __m512 b)` with a literal constant for the mask arg.

Comment: @PeterCordes The stated goal was "a shorter sequence of instructions." While this 1 instruction might not be very efficient, it's a short sequence so it seemed worth mentioning (with caveats).  Less so when "jit assembly" gets factored in.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Yeah, certainly worth mentioning.  But the OP *should* be measuring length in uops (for some uarches you care about, or for JIT just for the current target), with length in bytes as a tie-breaker.  Counting in instructions is often not relevant.  Loading from memory costs 4 bytes for the RIP-relative addressing mode  (beyond opcode + modrm, i.e. beyond what an EAX source would need) so it's only 1 byte shorter than mov-immediate + kmov for code-size.  Plus you still need to put the 2 bytes of data in a pool of constants somewhere, along with any vector constants.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**The normal way would be 2 single-uop instructions, 9 bytes.**

```
mov     $0xaaaa, %eax     # 5 bytes
kmovw   %eax, %k7         # 4 bytes
```

You can pick any scratch register; it doesn't have to be EAX.  But r8d..r15d would need a REX prefix on the `mov` costing 1 extra byte of code size.  (The 3-byte VEX prefix on `kmovw` already includes the REX bits so it wouldn't change size.)

**When you're not sure, you can and should have a look at what C compilers do.**  e.g. compile with `-O3` `return _mm512_maskz_add_ps (0xaaaa, a, b)` in a function with `__m512` args and see how it gets `0xaaaa` into a k register.

GCC, clang, and ICC don't always make optimal code, so if it looks sub-optimal you might have found a missed-optimization in the compiler.  Check https://uops.info/ and Agner Fog's microarch guide to see if there's a reason for the choice.

---

[`add eax, imm32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) is already 5 bytes, the same length as `mov eax, imm32`.  (And note that there's a 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` form with no modrm for every register, not just EAX).

xor-zero + add is 100% pointless.  In 32-bit mode (where 1-byte `inc`/`dec` is available, xor-zero + `inc` is sometimes used when optimizing for code-size over speed, but even `add r32, imm8` is 3 bytes.

Even for a small (8-bit) constant you'd only save 1 byte with xor-zero + 2-byte `mov al, imm8`, but at a cost of 2 uops for the front-end instead of 1 for `mov r32, imm32`. 
 **Performance is the reason compilers normally use `mov $1, %eax`** instead a slightly shorter 2-byte sequence, or a 3-byte `push imm8 / pop` that's even shorter but even less efficient.  See also [CodeGolf.SE's x86-64 machine-code tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code) for compact ways to put constants in registers.  e.g. if you already have a zeroed register, you can use a 3-byte LEA to get any value from -128 to +127 into another register.  It's only 1 uop but can't run on as many ports as `mov`-immediate.

**Generally code-size in bytes should only be considered as a tie-breaker between sequences that decode to as few uops as possible.**  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/

Counting in instructions is often not relevant.  But on Xeon Phi (Knight's Landing), avoiding multi-uop instructions is important.  The decoders stall for several cycles when one instruction has to decode to more than 1 uop.

Mainstream "big-core" x86 CPUs have a uops cache (Intel since Sandybridge, AMD since Zen), which mostly removes decode bottlenecks for hot loops.  (Tuning for earlier ISAs involved caring more about alignment and 16-byte fetch blocks, and whether a multi-uop instruction would line up with the first decoder or have to wait for the next cycle; see the Core2/Nehalem sections in Agner Fog's microarch PDF.)

Some instructions decode differently on different uarches, so your JIT could decode between sequences based on the current target.

---

**Loading a constant from memory: not worth it**

`kmovw  (mem), %k7` is encodeable, but unfortunately on Skylake-X / Cascade Lake / Ice Lake **it decodes to 2 uops**, like a `mov` load into EAX + a `kmov`.  So it still needs a uop for port 5.  https://www.uops.info/html-instr/KMOVW_K_M16.html

**It also barely saves anything for code-size: A RIP-relative addressing mode needs a 4-byte `rel32`** beyond the opcode + modrm, i.e. beyond what an EAX source would need.  So `kmovw constant(%rip), %k7` would be 8 bytes total, only 1 byte shorter than mov-immediate + kmov eax,k1.

Plus you still need to put the 2 bytes of data in a pool of constants somewhere, along with any vector constants.

But you will generally want to load vector constants from memory; they're much too large to construct efficiently from immediates + shuffles, unless it's a repeating pattern you can do with `mov $imm32, %eax` / `vpbroadcastd %eax, %zmm0`.  Or a repeating pattern you can construct on the fly from an all-ones register from `vpcmpeqd %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0` or `vpternlogd %zmm0, %zmm0, %zmm0, 0xff`.

SIMD vector loads are efficient; single uop.  Only mask-register loads are inefficient.

Comment: Update: GCC `-march=znver4` chooses to load mask constants from memory.  Presumably that's single-uop on AMD, unlike Intel.